# easy way to find out how many characters will be printed out (in general) by System.out.printf

Tags: java

Do you know any easy way to find out how many characters will be printed out by `System.out.printf(<<some arguments here>>)`. In c++ printf returns  the total number of characters written (on success).

In java, when we type:

```
System.out.println(System.out.printf(<<formula to check>>));
```

we will get sth like this:

```
java.io.PrintStream@700dce12
```

Comment: `printf` returns a `PrintStream` object. Basically, you are calling `.toString()` inherently on that object, which is why you see `java.io.PrintStream@700dce12`.  The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@`, and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
`getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `System.out.printf()` uses the same format options as `String.format()`, so you could probably just say:

```
int len = String.format("my format string", my, arguments).length();
```

Comment: Looking at the source, both end up calling `Formatter.format` with the same arguments, except that `printf` will use `Locale.getDefault()` and `String.format` uses `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)`.  If there's any chance those two are different, the lengths could be different.  Both `printf` and `String.format` take an optional `Locale` parameter, though.